# ConnectionRequest take time to postResponse

Tags: php, codenameone

here is an example of code that i write to make connection request.
In this example, i am sending a new password to the user when ever he forget it. But i have realised that when request is sent to the server side forget.php, the email is sent automatically  but the readResponse method takes  too much time before displaying the Dialog, this is not a low connection problem cause i have tested it with very hight speed connection

Can you tell what to do to make readResponse method be called once the server side have done his job?

```
ConnectionRequest requette=new ConnectionRequest(){
   Map data;

        @Override
        protected void postResponse(){

            String donnees=(String)data.get("reponse");
            Dialog.show("", "An email has been sent to you on "+em+"\nPlease check it to found out your password", "OK",null);

        }

        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input)throws IOException{

            JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
            data=parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));


        }



    };

    requette.setUrl(new ServerUrl().getServerUrl()+"/forget.php");
    requette.setPost(true);
    requette.setTimeout(15000);
    requette.addArgument("email", em);

    requette.setDisposeOnCompletion(new LoadingDialog(new Form()));
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(requette);
```

here is an example of how the server side script "forget.php "fis looking like:

```
<?php

 include("connexion_base.php");   
    $email=mysql_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

     $select=mysqli_query(connection(),"select * from users where email='$email'");


     if($r=mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
        $pw=$r["pw"];

        mail($email,"foganbidi","Your  password is:\n$pw\n","From:foganbidi");
        $sms.="Your  password is:$pw";


    }else{
        mail($email,"foganbidi@gmail.com","The email you submited does not exist in our database","From:foganbidi");
        $sms.="The email you submited  does not exist in our database";

    }


    $data=array("reponse"=>$sms);





    header("Content-Type:application/json");
    echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

here is how i check the code that is returned, but still running very slow, but in the browser the link runs fast

```
int rc=this.getResponseCode();
                if(rc==200){

                    System.out.println("the code is "+rc);
                    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
                    InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(input);
                    data=parser.parseJSON(is); 
                    System.out.println("the data is "+data);


                }
```

and for this simple request that i have made in a different project, it takes 20sec in simulator before reading the data

#

```
private void connect() {
         ConnectionRequest r=new ConnectionRequest(){

             Map data;


            @Override
            protected void handleException(Exception err){
                System.out.println("error coming from exception "+err.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException err){
                System.out.println("error coming from runtime "+err.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message){
                 System.out.println("ther response code is "+code+" and the message is "+message);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse(){

                System.out.println("ok for the data "+data);
            }

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input)throws IOException{

                int rc=this.getResponseCode();
                if(rc==200){


                    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
                    InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(input);
                    data=parser.parseJSON((Reader)is);




                }




            }

         };

         r.setUrl("http://localhost/craig/test2.php");
         r.setTimeout(5000);
         r.setPost(true);

         r.addArgument("nom", "faugan");

         InfiniteProgress progression=new InfiniteProgress();
         Dialog dd=progression.showInifiniteBlocking();
         r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dd);
         NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(r);

    }
```

#

Any help?

Comment: i edited it and i am having issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with PHP so I'm not really sure with this question (you can add php related taga for some help there).

This will happen if the response wasn't closed and our read is still waiting on the response code. I don't see where you set the response code to 200 so PHP might be holding the connection open here.

You can open the network monitor in the simulator and see what requests go out and the responses coming in.

Comment: how can  i close the connection?

Comment: @Override
   protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message){
      Dialog.show("Error", "The error code is "+code, "OK",null);     this code is not called, but when i made a mistake by making error in the url it sends 404 code, but when all is good i am not getting any code to check


   }

Comment: The PHP code should send a valid 200 response code or indicate in some way the response worked.

Comment: I am still having the same problem, i review all, even on my localhost the connection with the server is very slow, the response time is too long, and the app is runing too much slow, can you give me some tips to help me out?

Comment: please i added new explanation to my question, can you take a look?

Comment: You need to edit your question not add new answers. Try opening the URL in the browser and measure the amount of time that takes. You still aren't returning a return code from PHP

Comment: int rc=this.getResponseCode();
                if(rc==200){
                    
                    System.out.println("the code is "+rc);
                    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
                    InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(input);
                    data=parser.parseJSON(is); 
                    System.out.println("the data is "+data);
                   
                  
                } herer is how i checked the code, and it still slow, when  i access the url in a browser it runs faster, but in the app very very slow

Comment: "You still aren't returning a return code from PHP", how can i return code from php?

Comment: This is caused by the PHP side. This is really easy to test, just place a JSON string in dropbox or some other public URL and set the URL from the Codename One app to the dropbox public URL. You will notice this is fast.

Comment: Hi, thanks shai, i just use another computer with the same version of netbeans and codenameone, when i run the app in localhost, it runs very faster than the old machine i am using, can the computer's configuration affect the apk of the app? that have no sense  but that is what i am realising,

Comment: Networking can be affected by **many** things, you need to isolate the issue

Comment: OK then i am going to compile with the other machine to see how faster it will be